# How can I install RabbitSVN in Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora

How can I install Rabbit SVN in Fedora? Once installed, what are the steps involved in using it in Fedora?

Comment: As for steps involved in using it, we probably need to know what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about [RabbitVCS](http://www.rabbitvcs.org/), which handles SVN.  As for installing it, it is in the standard Fedora repos.  Just do a :

```
yum install rabbitvcs-svn
```

or a:

```
yum install rabbitvcs*
```

which will install all RabbitVCS components.

If you only want select packages, a `yum search rabbitvcs` will show you what is available.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://github.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs/issues/43), for Fedora 22 (haven't tried others) you will also have to install another package:

```
sudo dnf install python-simplejson
```